# Merge binary trees in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, merge, functional-programming, binary-tree

It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635141/algorithm-of-combining-two-binary-trees#4635151):

> The easiest way to merge two binary trees is to take iterate down the
>   left child of one tree until reaching a node without a left child.
>   Then add the other tree's root as the left child.

Easy. In "normal code", I'd write something like this:

```
if(!left.isEmpty)
  thisFuncAgain()
else left = otherSet; return this
```

However, I cannot imagine how this would look in Scala. Here are some of my thoughts. This function would go in the `BinaryTree` class:

```
def merg(that: BinaryTree): BinaryTree = {
  if(leftNode.isEmpty) leftNode += that; leftNode
  else merg(leftNode)
}
```

However, reassigning to a `val` is not possible. I could recurse this function for the left node but then when it returned, the elements previous to the last node would not be accounted for.

Any tips on how I could think of this?
I'm a beginner in Scala and I'm really stuck at this.

Comment: Can we see your `BinaryTree` class.

Comment: The way to think of it is that your new, merged `BinaryTree` will _share_ nodes with the old `BinaryTrees`. Chris Okasaki's book [_Purely Functional Data Structures_](http://books.google.com/books?id=IV8hAwAAQBAJ) is an excellent source on this approach. Happily, his Ph.D. dissertation, which the book is based on, is available for free [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the `BinaryTree` class looks like, and you do not tell much about that. It is completely possible to have a mutable `BinaryTree`, where you can modify a node. But here is an implementation on your algorithm with a typical immutable `BinaryTree`

```
sealed trait BinaryTree[A] {
  def merge(that: BinaryTree[A]): BinaryTree[A]
}
case object Empty extends BinaryTree[Nothing] {
  def merge(that: BinaryTree[A]: BinaryTree[A] = that
}
case class Node(left: BinaryTree[A], value: A, right: BinaryTree[A]) 
extends BinaryTree[A] {
  def merge(that: BinaryTree[A]): BinaryTree[A] =
   Node(left.merge(that), value, right)
}
```

It does not modify `this`, it returns new instances of `BinaryTree`, and leaves `this` unchanged. It is not that costly, as all the nodes of `that` and most of the nodes of `this` will be shared between the two trees. The only nodes that needs to be recreated are between the root of this and its leftmost node. You gain the benefit of immutability, foremost that it is freely shareable, you never need to make a defensive copy.

On the other hand, it is quite possible to make left and right children `var` rather than `val` and to have merge mutate the original tree.

---

You state in comment that it just return the tree to be merged. It does not. There was a typo in Node.merge I just fixed, maybe it is what confused you. Mabye what confuses you is that  return is usually not written scala. In the two implementations of merge, you may put a return, `return that` and `return Node(left.merge...`, it would mean the very same thing. Also, `return Node(...)` is the same as `return new Node(...)`. Anyway, here is how it works

Suppose the values are integers, and `this` is

```
    5
   / \
  7   C
 / \
2   B
 \
  A
```

`A`, `B`, `C` may be single nodes, whole trees, empty, we don't care, the point is that the left child of 2 is empty and this is where the merge will take place.

`that` will simply be `M`, because what it contains does not matter. Let's go.

`this` is `Node([node 7], 5, C)`

We call merge on that :

```
Node([node 7], 5, C).merge(M)
```

It returns

```
Node([node 7].merge(M), 5, C)
```

The point is that this code does not return `this`. It returns a new node, where the left child is not what it was in the original node. It is no longer `[node 7]`, it is `[node 7].merge(M)`. So let's compute `[node 7].merge(M)`. `[node 7]` is `Node([node 2], 7, B)`. Let's merge M into that.

```
[node 7].merge(M) = Node([node 2], 7, B).merge(M) 
                  = Node([node2].merge(M), 7, B).
```

Again, in the returned node, we replace the left child.  One more time: [node2] is Node(Empty, 2, A), so:

```
[node 2].merge(M) = Node(Empty, 2, A).merge(M) 
                  = Node(Empty.merge(M), 2, A).
```

Now we get to the bottom. `Empty.merge(M)` is `M`. We just need to rewind and all will comme in place.

```
[node 2].merge(M) = Node(Empty, 2, A).merge(M) 
                  = Node(Empty.merge(M), 2, A) 
                  = Node(M, 2, A)

    2
   / \
  M   A
```

As you see, we have actually done something. M is under 2 in the result.

Another step up:

```
[node 7].merge(m) = Node([node 2], 7, B).merge(M) 
                  = Node([Node 2].merge(M), 7, B).
```

Now we know what [node2].merge(M) means. So

```
Node([node 2], 7, B).merge(M) = Node(Node(M, 2, A), 7, B)

    7
   / \
  2   B
 / \
M   A
```

We have [node 7].merge(m), so we can compute the final result :

```
this.merge(m) = Node([node 7].merge(m), 5, C)
```

We know what `[node 7].merge(m)` is, so the final result, as intended :

```
        5
       / \
      7   C
     / \
    2   B
   / \
  M   A
```

Comment: How is it that the new tree holds all of his values? From what I can understand it will recursively loop each time until it finds an empty in which case it returns the tree-to-be-merged?

Comment: See completed answer.

Comment: So the left-most will end up as the `that`. This explanation made it so much more clear. +1